# BackboneJS resyncing collection URL to Model after another model is destroyed

Tags: url, model-view-controller, backbone.js, collections, destroy

I am having an issue with persisting a collection define URL for CRUD operations after I delete a model. I have a few models, one for each contact. Currently I run a this.model.destroy when I want to delete a contact, though as soon as I destroy the model, I am getting an undefined status for the collection defined URL. Is there a way to re-establish the collection-defined URL for all other models after a destroy?

I have tried to define a rootURL, which seems to work after a deleted contact, however, if I am not deleting a contact, then I get multiple requests to send the same contact with different ID's

Here is the Delete functionality:

```
  deleteContact: function() {

    if (!this.model) {
        return;
    }

    this.model.destroy({
        success: function(model, response) {
            App.Emitter.trigger('snackbar', 'Contact Deleted!', 3000);
            App.Emitter.trigger('contacts:close');
            App.Master.changeView('contacts');
            Backbone.Collection.fetch()
            // App.Contacts2.remove(this.model);
        },
        error: function(model, response) {
            console.info('contact save error');
            App.Emitter.trigger('snackbar', 'ERROR Deleting!', 3000);
        }
    });
},
```

I am getting an error:

"
app.min.js:1552 Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified"

Comment: it looks like a collection problem ? where is the collection code ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that even though I was removing the Model, the view was sticking around in the background. The URL issue I was receiving was being thrown since it is a required field (but being thrown from a 'ghost' view that stacked up in the background). Thanks for the help.